The use of subjunctives and conditionals in a sentence
I came up with the following sentence:

The upstream is set to <start-point> regardless, be <start-point> a local or remote-tracking branch or should the branch names match or not.

In other words:

The upstream is set to <start-point>, regardless of whether <start-point> is a local branch or a remote-tracking branch, and regardless of whether the branch names match.

I guess the former version doesn't sound particularly good, but I'd like to know what exactly is wrong.
The latter version is probably to be preferred, but it's kind of boring (I'm more interested in informal speech). On the other hand subjunctive or "should" can probably make it sound more formal or archaic. I'm not sure.
UPD It basically comes down to:

A is true regardless, be B C or D or should E and F match or not.

A version suggested by Stuart F:

The upstream is set to <start-point> regardless, be <start-point> a local or remote-tracking branch or be the branch names matching or not.


You're mixing two constructions, "be..." and "should...", which is why it's ugly. I guess you could make the second part "or be the branch names matching or not" but that's not very idiomatic. It depends if you want to emphasize that the same thing will be done regardless of the circumstances (is this surprising or counter-intuitive?). I'd stick with "whether" or similar e.g. "The upstream is set to , whether  is a local or remote-tracking branch, and whether the branch names match or not."

@StuartF Do I use "should" in place of "be" for emphasis? No. And generally the fact that is stated by the phrase shouldn't be surprising.

It's confusing because it's hard to tell whether there are four independent alternatives, or two alternatives in each option.

@Barmar Is it confusing only in the first version (be...should)? I added to the question a "logical structure" of the sentence and the version suggested by Stuart F. In the sentence I consider 2 aspects: a) B is C or D, b) E equals F or not. This gives 4 cases. Independent ones. In all 4 cases A is true. And the list of cases is exhaustive I believe. I'm not sure what exactly is confusing. I think It should be clear that there are 2 aspects in the sentence (a and b). Whether they're independent or not... I'm not sure how they can be dependent actually. If B is C then E always equal F?

"or should" helps a little, but it kind of looks like "A or B or C or D"
